# Why is Paypal redirect message not appearing?

Tags: redirect, paypal

I have built 2 sites which both can take Paypal payments.
But for one of these sites the redirect message that says a user will be redirected in 10 seconds doesn't appear.
It just says the payment has been completed successfully although it does indeed redirect back to my site after 10 seconds.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the redirect message to not appear and how I would fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have [Auto-Return](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside) enabled on one but not the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no I checked the settings for both and Auto-Return is enabled on both. Checking the Paypal settings for both sites' Paypal addresses I can't seem to find any differences which would explain the different behavior.

Comment: Are they both using Payments Standard or are you working with different API's on the different sites?  Maybe you're using Standard on one but Adaptive Payments API's on another, for example..??